# removing space between ggrepel label made using plotmath

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath, ggrepel

I am creating a plot where I want to display labels using `ggrepel`. I am showing a minimal example below that illustrates how the label has two components separated by a comma - first related to the type of iris flower species and the second to the sample size for that group.

```r
# needed libraries
set.seed(123)
library(ggrepel)

# creating a dataframe with label column
(df <- iris %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Species) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = n(), mean = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  purrrlyr::by_row(
    .d = .,
    ..f = ~ paste("list(~",
                  .$Species,
                  ",",
                  .$n,
                  ")",
                  sep = ""),
    .collate = "rows",
    .to = "label",
    .labels = TRUE
  ))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Species        n  mean label               
#>   <fct>      <int> <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1 setosa        50  5.01 list(~setosa,50)    
#> 2 versicolor    50  5.94 list(~versicolor,50)
#> 3 virginica     50  6.59 list(~virginica,50)

# displaying labels
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(data = df,
                            aes(x = Species, y = mean, label = label),
                            parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

My question is how I can get rid of the space between these two components. Although I have specified `sep = ""` in `paste()` function, there is still extra space between two components that I don't want (e.g., `setosa, 50`, `versicolor, 50`, `virginica, 50` labels should instead be `setosa,50`, `versicolor,50`, `virginica,50`).

Comment: For your simple example you could make your labels in such a way that you don't need to parse them.  If you use `dplyr::mutate(label = paste0(Species, ",", n))` and remove `parse = TRUE` from `geom_label_repel()` you don't get the extra space.  I'm guessing you have reasons to use the label-making code you did on your real use case but I don't think it's needed here.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. My actual function displays equations, so that's why I am using plotmath in a list and then parsing it. Here is an example- https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/articles/ggcoefstats.html#repeated-measures-anova-aovlist. Look at the degrees of freedom for F-statistic. There is a space between numerator df and denominator df that I want to remove and thus the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an updated version of your code, which implements a way to place the comma (without a succeeding space) between the Species name and the sample size. You labels, for example,  will look like `"~setosa*\",\"*50"` instead of `list(~setosa,50)`

```
(df <- iris %>%
    dplyr::group_by(Species) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(n = n(), mean = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
    purrrlyr::by_row(
      .d = .,
      ..f = ~ paste("~",
                    .$Species,
                    "*\",\"*",
                    .$n,
                    "",
                    sep = ""),
      .collate = "rows",
      .to = "label",
      .labels = TRUE
    ))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Species        n  mean label               
#>   <fct>      <int> <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1 setosa        50  5.01 "~setosa*\",\"*50"
#> 2 versicolor    50  5.94 "~versicolor*\",\"*50"
#> 3 virginica     50  6.59 "~virginica*\",\"*50"


# displaying labels
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="lm",size=0.6,se=FALSE,colour="black")+
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(data = df,
                            aes(x = Species, y = mean, label = label),
                            parse = TRUE)
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image: Plot with labels without spaces]

Hope it helps.